# How can I analyze the header and body posted by my API call

Tags: java, java-http-client

In Java, using httpclient5.1.3 and httpcore5.1.3 I'm trying to do a POST request to an API URL. However, I keep receiving a 400 Bad request. Are there any tools so I can debug how the request is exactly received by the API? To see how the headers and body are received exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Postman or Advanced Rest Client (A plugin for Chrome) that allows you to send HTTP requests and see the responses. There is a tool called Fidler that shows HHTP traffic.

Also there are some other HTTP clients you could use:

1. [Apache Http client](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/index.html) - very popular and well known 3d party Http Client
2. [OK Http client](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-ok-http-client/) - Open-source Http client. [Here](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaLibrary-OkHttp/article.html) is tutorial
3. MgntUtils Http client - very simple 3d party HttpClient: Provided in MgntUtils Open source library (written by me). Very simple in use. Take a look at [Javadoc](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/lifecycle/management/httpclient/HttpClient.html). Library itself provided as [Maven artifacts](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils/1.5.0.7/jar) and on [Git](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases/tag/1.5.0.7) (including source code and Javadoc).